# Match número fracionado javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Tenho um script e em uma das linhas:

```
return $flag.text().match(/[0-9 ]+(?=\%)/i);
```

lê os números de uma *tag* `p`.

Ex:

```
<p>Desconto 15%</p>
```

No caso ele irá ler o número 15.

Pelo o que sei essa linha não lê o número com ponto ou vírgula ex: 9,09 ou 9.09 `<br/>`.

Nesse exemplo caso ele lê somente até a vírgula, como eu faria para esse script ler os números após a vírgula ?

Comment: Acabei de testar e infelizmente não :/

Comment: Thiago, a resposta abaixo resolveu o problema? [**aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwny46g/2/) tem uma expressão variante daquela postada na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa adicionar um `.` e `,` na expressão deixando assim *`/[0-9,\.]+(?=\%)/`*. O modificador `i` não é necessário nessa situação.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwny46g/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Cara infelizmente num funfo :(

Comment: Não irá funcionar se tiver "espaço" exemplo `15 %`